# Ensure divs never cross each other

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have 2 divs that are side by side and each have a width of 50% and float left what I want however is that if they cannot fit on the page that one div should drop below the other div. How can I do this in CSS? I should also mention am using jQuery Mobile if that makes a difference. My code is below:
`#artistimage,#artistinfo{
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            }`

Comment: If they are 50% of the width, they will always "fit", won't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/PMXpb/ they always fit when they are set 50% width.
`{width:50%; height: 100px; float:left;}`

If you set them at a fixed width (a pixel value) the one will drop below the other when there will be not enough space, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yk4sX/
    `{width:300px; height: 100px; float:left;}`

You can test the 2 cases by resizing the browser.

Comment: Thanks I guess when my browser did some mess when I was building it and changed the browser size because they crossed at that time